# build Scipy matrix with diagonal overlays

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy

I would like to overlay several arrays of equal 4x4 size at offset positions creating a large array where the overlapping elements are added together.

```
[a] 0 0 0
 0 [a+b] 0 0
 0 0 [b+c] 0
 0 0 0 [c+...
```

This is for the creation of a stiffness matrix for continuous beam analysis. This is easy enough to create with a loop, but is there a better way using Scipy sparse matrix routines? block_diag is close but does not provide a method for overlays.

```
Members = [[100.0, 1000.0],[100.0, 2000.0],[200.0, 2000.0]]

SSM = np.zeros((2*M+2,2*M+2), dtype = float)
i=0
for mem in Members:
    a = SMX(mem)
    print a
    print "*"*40

    SSM[i:i+4,i:i+4] = SSM[i:i+4,i:i+4] + a
    print SSM
    i +=2

def SMX(member):
    """ Prismatic beam member stiffness function
    Purpose: Create a member stiffness matrix for a given set of member parameters.
    Input:  Modulus of elasticity - E
            Moment of inertia with respect to the z axis - Iz
            Length of the span - L

    Returns: 4 x 4 matrix representing the member stiffness with respect to end conditions    
"""

    L = member[0]
    Iz = member[1]

    pbms = np.zeros((4,4), dtype = float)

    pbms[0,0] = (12.0 * E * Iz)/L**2
    pbms[0,1] = (6.0 * E * Iz)/L**2
    pbms[0,2] = -pbms[0,0]
    pbms[0,3] = pbms[0,1]

    pbms[1,0] = pbms[0,1]
    pbms[1,1] = (4.0 * E * Iz)/L
    pbms[1,2] = -pbms[0,1]
    pbms[1,3] = (2.0 * E * Iz)/L

    pbms[2,0] = pbms[0,2]
    pbms[2,1] = -pbms[0,1]
    pbms[2,2] = pbms[0,0]
    pbms[2,3] = -pbms[0,1]

    pbms[3,0] = pbms[0,1]
    pbms[3,1] = pbms[1,3]
    pbms[3,2] = -pbms[0,1]
    pbms[3,3] = pbms[1,1]

    return pbms
```

The resulting output:

```
[[  12000.    6000.  -12000.    6000.]
 [   6000.  400000.   -6000.  200000.]
 [ -12000.   -6000.   12000.   -6000.]
 [   6000.  200000.   -6000.  400000.]]
****************************************
[[  12000.    6000.  -12000.    6000.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [   6000.  400000.   -6000.  200000.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [ -12000.   -6000.   12000.   -6000.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [   6000.  200000.   -6000.  400000.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.]]
[[  24000.   12000.  -24000.   12000.]
 [  12000.  800000.  -12000.  400000.]
 [ -24000.  -12000.   24000.  -12000.]
 [  12000.  400000.  -12000.  800000.]]
****************************************
[[   12000.     6000.   -12000.     6000.        0.        0.        0.
         0.]
 [    6000.   400000.    -6000.   200000.        0.        0.        0.
         0.]
 [  -12000.    -6000.    36000.     6000.   -24000.    12000.        0.
         0.]
 [    6000.   200000.     6000.  1200000.   -12000.   400000.        0.
         0.]
 [       0.        0.   -24000.   -12000.    24000.   -12000.        0.
         0.]
 [       0.        0.    12000.   400000.   -12000.   800000.        0.
         0.]
 [       0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
         0.]
 [       0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
         0.]]
[[   6000.    3000.   -6000.    3000.]
 [   3000.  400000.   -3000.  200000.]
 [  -6000.   -3000.    6000.   -3000.]
 [   3000.  200000.   -3000.  400000.]]
****************************************
[[   12000.     6000.   -12000.     6000.        0.        0.        0.
         0.]
 [    6000.   400000.    -6000.   200000.        0.        0.        0.
         0.]
 [  -12000.    -6000.    36000.     6000.   -24000.    12000.        0.
         0.]
 [    6000.   200000.     6000.  1200000.   -12000.   400000.        0.
         0.]
 [       0.        0.   -24000.   -12000.    30000.    -9000.    -6000.
      3000.]
 [       0.        0.    12000.   400000.    -9000.  1200000.    -3000.
    200000.]
 [       0.        0.        0.        0.    -6000.    -3000.     6000.
     -3000.]
 [       0.        0.        0.        0.     3000.   200000.    -3000.
    400000.]]
```

Just noticed that I left out M = 3 above.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of 4x4 arrays, or a sequence of arrays whose length is variable?  (The `...` makes me think the latter.)  What goes in the final block?

Comment: Is your sample desired output correct, or do you really want something like the array shown on page 12 of http://www.ce.memphis.edu/7117/notes/presentations/chapter_03a.pdf, where the individual 2x2 arrays are (ignoring the multiplicative constant) `[[1, -1], [-1, 1]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem with [`scipy.sparse.block_diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.block_diag.html), but I probably don't understand exactly what you mean by "overlay".  For example, the output you illustrated in the question can be formed like this:

```
In [41]: from scipy import sparse

In [42]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [43]: b = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

In [44]: c = np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]])

In [45]: m = sparse.block_diag([a, a+b, b+c])

In [46]: m.A
Out[46]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 12,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 14, 16],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 18, 20]])
```

*Edit*: After browsing through some material on beam analysis, I think I understand better how you want to overlay the matrices.

For example, suppose there are four 2x2 arrays a, b, c, and d.  An example of an "overlay" is the following:

```
a[0,0]     a[0,1]            0              0            0
a[1,0]  a[1,1]+b[0,0]     b[0,1]            0            0
  0        b[1,0]      b[1,1]+c[0,0]     c[0,1]          0
  0           0           c[1,0]      c[1,1]+d[0,0]  d[0,1]
  0           0              0           d[1,0]      d[1,1]
```

One way to form this with `block_diag` is demonstrated here. It involves an expression with a term for each 2x2 array, which could be rewritten as a loop, so it doesn't really answer your question.

```
In [92]: a,b,c,d
Out[92]: 
(array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]),
 array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]]),
 array([[ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]]),
 array([[13, 14],
       [15, 16]]))

In [93]: bd = sparse.block_diag  # A convenient alias

In [94]: m = bd([a,0,0,0])+bd([0,b,0,0])+bd([0,0,c,0])+bd([0,0,0,d])

In [95]: m.A
Out[95]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  9,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  7, 17, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 11, 25, 14],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15, 16]])
```

Comment: Warren, Thanks for the help. Your explanation of the sparse.block_diag really helped. Unfortunately, I still cannot achieve my desired matrix. I've uploaded my code and results above for you to review if you have time. This is my first real 'question' so forgive me if I've not properly formatted everything. Thanks again for the excellent help.

Comment: While some variation of what I put in my answer could be created for your 4x4 case, I don't think it will be any better than what you already have.  And if your example is typical (i.e. three members), you won't gain anything using a spare matrix.

Comment: Warren, Continuous beams can be any number of spans, but usually between 2 and 6 spans are typical. Thanks again for the help and especially for the explanation of block_diag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`coo_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix). You need to supply three arrays: the data, the row indices and the column indices as per the second example in the link. The key point being:

> By default when converting to CSR or CSC format, duplicate (i,j) entries will be summed together. This facilitates efficient
>   construction of finite element matrices and the like. (see example)

Comment: Thank you. This seems a very complicated method, especially since several sub arrays must be combined together to form a larger one. Can you point me to an example other than the one from Scipy docs?

Comment: @Ron if you can post your existing code that creates the output with the loop along with the input (best as runnable Python code) then hopefully I can show you how to use it with this method. In the end it is usually not too complicated, especially if you use [`mgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) or similar to get the indices.